# Sticky element flickering on scroll (Chrome device toolbar activated)

Tags: css, sticky

I have an issue regarding a `position: sticky` element that flickers whenever I scroll the page in Google Chrome using the device toolbar and simulate different devices. However, when I don't use the device toolbar, the element works as it supposed to. It looks fine in Safari and Firefox as well. I saw a couple of workarounds using `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` and `backface-visibility: hidden;`, but I cant't seem to get it to work.
I'm using it inside a Next.js project.

Anybody experienced the same thing?

This is the css for the sticky element:

```
.StateTitle {
position: sticky;
top: 0;
padding-top: 45px;
z-index: 50;
width: 100%;
padding-bottom: 1px; 
background-color: #FF7E7E;
```

}

And this is the css for the parent element:

```
.StateWrapper {
margin-top: 0;
width: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
position: relative;
```

}